# Convering a whole number to this format 120m59s

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

Ive looked online and searched and asked but no one can answer my question I need to format a whole number Eg: 12059 to look like this 120m59s. Ive tried with moment.js to do it and Im getting an error.
 `TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.duration(...).format is not a function`

if I do it like so  `data.total ? moment.duration(data.total, 'seconds').format('m [min] s [sec]') : '0'`

Could someone please help ?

Comment: First off, 12059 seconds is not 120 minutes and 59 seconds. In addition, I do not see that a momentjs duration object has a `format` function that behaves like that. See the [Momentjs Duration Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Comment: you don't need moment for this, if you know the first 2 digits are your seconds you can just convert the number into a string and split it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out - `moment.utc(moment.duration(data.total, 'seconds').asMilliseconds()).format('h[h]m[m]s[s]')`

Took me a few struggles and costed a handful of hairs but I hear balding is the new thing.